# 24 hours countdown that restarts once page refreshes

Tags: javascript, html, css

i created this countdown that counts down 24 hours but once the page is refreshed,it restarts the countdown
how can i make it not start again?
please can anyone help me understand what i can do or to make it a static countdown

here are the codes

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  const seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
  const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  const hours = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  const days = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  return {
    total,
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  const clock = document.getElementById(id);
  const daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  const hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  const minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  const secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    const t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  const timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

const deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
  <div id="clockdiv">
    <div>
      <span class="days"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="hours"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="seconds"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i'd really appreciate any help regarding this
I dont know what way to go about it

Comment: You need to persist the values somewhere in the browser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage

Comment: Store the time in local storage and print it whenever you need to refresh the clock. And when the page reloads first check whether is there time set in the local storage, if yes then get it, print it and then refresh it normally. If no then do the standard way and restart the clock.

Comment: Do you want to start it from where it was stopped, or it should display the remaining time until deadline?

Answer (score 1):

To not restart the countdown once the page is refreshed, the deadline data needs to be saved into a persistent storage that does not get cleared out even when the page is refreshed. You can achieve this by storing the deadline data in localStorage.

> localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except that while localStorage data has no expiration time, sessionStorage data gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed. - Source: [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

The change required on your code:

```
    let deadline;
    const prevDeadLine = localStorage.getItem("deadlineData"); // Get previous data from local storage
    if (!prevDeadLine) {
      deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      localStorage.setItem("deadlineData", deadline); // set the data for the first time
    } else {
      deadline = prevDeadLine;  // use previousDeadline
    }
```

**Solution Snippet:**

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Countdown
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
      <div id="clockdiv">
        <div>
          <span class="days"></span>
          <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="hours"></span>
          <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="minutes"></span>
          <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="seconds"></span>
          <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
      const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
      const seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
      const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      const hours = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      const days = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

      return {
        total,
        days,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds
      };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
      const clock = document.getElementById(id);
      const daysSpan = clock.querySelector(".days");
      const hoursSpan = clock.querySelector(".hours");
      const minutesSpan = clock.querySelector(".minutes");
      const secondsSpan = clock.querySelector(".seconds");

      function updateClock() {
        const t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ("0" + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ("0" + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ("0" + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timeinterval);
        } else {
          new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        }
      }

      updateClock();
      const timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
    let deadline;
    const prevDeadLine = localStorage.getItem("deadlineData");
    if (!prevDeadLine) {
      deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      localStorage.setItem("deadlineData", deadline);
    } else {
      deadline = prevDeadLine;
    }

    initializeClock("clockdiv", deadline);
  </script>
</html>
```